# how we can get the result export from Arango DB noSQL

Tags: python, shell, arangodb, nosql

I am very new to arango DB nosql
I try to get the exported output of arangoDB with shell commands or arangosh commands but I could not find any way. I know serialization to application can definitely help. However, I am looking for cli methods to get it done.

There is a way to use pyarango where we can ostream the results to file. However looking for solution like 
`echo " db._query('return (length(table_name))')"|arangosh --server.database "qadb"  --server.endpoint "tcp://127.0.0.1:8529" --server.username "qatest" --server.password "TTT"`

However, In my case I could get the results and command ended to open the arangosh shell. Please help to make understanding.

Comment: What you are asking for doesn't sound like a good way to query for data. But if you really want to, you can do something like this: `arangosh --server.database qadb --server.username qatest --server.password TTTT --javascript.execute-string "print(db._query('RETURN LENGTH(collection_name)'))"`

Answer (score 2):

ArangoDB offers several ways of scripting. You can use [curl as documented with the HTTP-API](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/HTTP/Database/index.html)

```
curl --dump - http://localhost:8529/_api/version?details=true
```

The HTTP-API is what all drivers are based on. So if its possible to achieve via arangosh, you can do it with curl (maybe with the aid of [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to extract the required information)

You can also use arangosh to execute arbitrary commands passed in (as pointed out by CoDEmanX:

```
arangosh --server.database qadb \
  --server.username qatest \
  --server.password TTTT \
  --javascript.execute-string \
    "print(db._query('RETURN LENGTH(collection_name)'))"
```

You can also use `arangosh` to run scripts using the standard unix shebang mechanism:

```
#!/usr/bin/arangosh --javascript-execute 
print(db._query('RETURN LENGTH(collection_name)'));
```

Save the above to i.e. `/tmp/test.js` and make it executable with `chmod a+x /tmp/test.js`, you then can simply invoke it:

```
/tmp/test.js
SOME_BASH_VAR=`/tmp/test.js`
echo "${SOME_BASH_VAR}"
/tmp/test.js > /tmp/output_of_arangosh.json
```

To generally export collections you should use [arangodump](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Administration/Arangodump.html).